# Static resource rendering

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to render static resources in Spring.  Despite add the  annotation, Spring is not rendering it.

Here is the snapshot:
[image]

Steps I have taken:
1. Added mvc:resources to my servlet.xml
2. Created a resources folder and added hello.html

URL I am tyring to address: http://localhost:8080/StellarReceive/resources/hello.html

Comment: Just move the `resources` folder to be under WEB-INF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the `resources` folder to be under `WEB-INF`